# Enable Android System Touch Sounds

Tags: android, settings, system, audio

I'm trying to enable/disable the touch sounds programmatically from an Service.

What I did until now is:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), 
    Settings.System.SOUND_EFFECTS_ENABLED, 
    SOUND_EFFECTS);
```

`SOUND_EFFECTS` can be **0**(disabled) or **1**(enabled)

But it doesn't affect the general settings - The settings in the Android OS remain unchanged ... so if I manually change them, the above code doesn't change them accordingly.

How do I change those settings programmatically ? Like Keytone, Touch sounds, Screen lock sound ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think u are missing permission for this . Add all the following permissions.

1. **public static final String MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS**   Constant Value:android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"
2. **public static final String WRITE_SETTINGS**  Constant Value: "android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"